# how do i include C/ C++ graphics.h when im using the code for node.js

Tags: node.js, add-on, bgi

I have to work with the `C & C++` API's using `node.js`.. the problem is my `C` code includes `graphics.h` file which is not found in `node.js`.. i don't have any alternate for graphics.h.